# resolve bigbluebutton repository in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, apt-get, bigbluebutton

i am iranian ubuntu user and Iran is in sanction.
i want to add some foreign repositories in my ubuntu server
i got many `ign` in my `apt-get update`
how can i solve this problem???
foreign repository is [bigBlueButton](https://bigbluebutton.org)

if any way is to resolve this problem tell me please!!!